# Check whether console is present

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am writing a plugin. For that I will log a few things, say warnings, necc things, etc. To log them I will use console, but there can be an error if some browser doesn't support console. To handle this error, I am thinking of using this code:

```
    if (typeof console == 'undefined') console = {};
if (typeof console.log == 'undefined') console.log = function() {};
if (typeof console.debug == 'undefined') console.debug = function() {};
if (typeof console.info == 'undefined') console.info = function() {};
if (typeof console.warn == 'undefined') console.warn = function() {};
if (typeof console.error == 'undefined') console.error = function() {};
```

Will this work right or is there a better option?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You're approaching it right. You could however shorten it a bit:

```
if(typeof console === "undefined") {
    console = {
        log: function() { },
        debug: function() { },
        ...
    };
}
```

This allows you to use `console.log/console.debug etc` without first checking if a console object is defined. I recommend to always include this snippet if you are logging since it is easy to forget to remove and it will break your site if no console is present.

Answer (score 9):

This approach makes it easier to add/change/remove methods in the future and is more elegant and less redundant than most offered:

```
if (!"console" in window || typeof console == "undefined") {
    var methods = ["log", "debug", "info", "warn", "error", "assert", "dir", "dirxml", "group", "groupEnd", "time", "timeEnd", "count", "trace", "profile", "profileEnd"];
    var emptyFn = function () {};
    window.console = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < methods.length; ++i) {
        window.console[methods[i]] = emptyFn;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using a library for logging?

- [YUI Console](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/console/)
- [log4j](http://log4javascript.org/)
- [jsnlog](http://js.jsnlog.com/)
- [loglevel](https://github.com/pimterry/loglevel)

**UPDATE:** You could use the below script to avoid `console` errors in browsers that lack a console.

https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/src/js/plugins.js

Answer (score 1):

```
console && console.log("whatever");
```

Does this not work ?

Comment: I believe you can do `console.log("whatever") || true;` or something similar.  I saw it a couple of months back and can't remember exactly how the dev had done it but I think that's correct.

Comment: @Endophage If console is not supported you'll get a "Cannot call method 'log' of undefined", A correct on line check would be:
`console && console.log && console.log("whatever")`

Answer (score 0):

How about shortening @alexn 's answer a bit

```
window.console = window.console || { debug: function(){}, log: function() { } };
```