# script not working in IE 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, internet-explorer-9

i have this script for the check of a checkbox, it works well in firefox and google chrome, however it does not work in IE 9

```
    $notifyBySmsCheckbox
  .change(function(){
    if (this.checked) {console.log('checked');
      $('#f_notify_by_sms_instructions, #f_notify_by_sms_pin, #cellphoneInfo').show();
    }
    else {console.log('not checked');
      $('#f_notify_by_sms_instructions, #f_notify_by_sms_pin, #cellphoneInfo').hide();
    }
  })
  .change();
```

anyone know why this is??

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: Please provide some basic information and do some basic research yourself. Like for instance: what do you expect that this does, what does actually happen, is there an error (either in the url-bar showing javascript error, or in the console), what html do you have, etc. etc. Help us help you.

Comment: You can write that if/else as just `$('#f_notify_by_sms_instructions, #f_notify_by_sms_pin, #cellphoneInfo').toggle(this.checked);`

Comment: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2vHD3/) showing toggle

Comment: U should check for console.log.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036377/check-whether-console-is-present

Answer (score 5):

..it's most likely because IE doesn't have a console object. Try and remove the console.log's and you'll be fine!

Comment: An alternative is to press F12 then refresh the page.

Answer (score 3):

Only access `console` when it's defined:

```
  $notifyBySmsCheckbox.change(function() {   
    if (this.checked) {
      console && console.log('checked');
      $('#f_notify_by_sms_instructions, #f_notify_by_sms_pin, #cellphoneInfo').show();
    } else {
      console && console.log('not checked');
      $('#f_notify_by_sms_instructions, #f_notify_by_sms_pin, #cellphoneInfo').hide();
    }
  })
```

Also, you can use [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) to simplify your code, as suggested by @epascarello:

```
  $notifyBySmsCheckbox.change(function() {
    console && console.log(this.checked ? "checked" : "not checked");
    $('#f_notify_by_sms_instructions, #f_notify_by_sms_pin, #cellphoneInfo').toggle(this.checked);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

... it will work if you have dev tools open in ie, otherwise it won't. Do you have to support ie 8 and 7? - if so you'll have problems with the onchange event in these. Use onClick instead.